# Passing a variable as a foreign key

Tags: cakephp

I am developing a simple CRM system.

1. User opens Customer index.ctp to see customer list
2. User selects Customer X and goes to view.ctp for that customer (e.g. is directed to Customers/View/5... i currently have a View button inside the table beside each row)
3. Customer X can have multiple addresses below in second table
4. User can click 'Add New' address which goes to add.ctp for Addresses
5. Customer ID is passed from Customers/view/X as the foreign key on Addresses/add

I have the first four steps working.

For number 5, I imagine there are a number of ways. Possibly by passing a variable across?

I want to add a new address, from the customer view, without selecting the customer a second time. On the Addresses/add.ctp I don't need the customer name or ID shown, just to end up as the foreign key somehow.

Comment: well well... the old brain is still working after all... I worked out one method that worked (not sure if it's ideal but it did the job)...

Comment: In my Customer index view, here is my link to add the new address:

<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Address'), array('controller' => 'CustomerAddress','action' => 'add', $custid));

In my CustomerAddress Controller, Add function I added '$custid = null'

public function add($custid = null)

I also added this line after is post:
$this->request->data['CustomerAddress']['customer_id'] = $custid;

i.e.
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
 $this->request->data['CustomerAddress']['customer_id'] = $custid;

Comment: Please do not post code or answers in comments, it's highly unreadable, and not helpful for future readers. Instead update your question, or post a proper answer in case you've solved your problem - thanks!

Comment: Are you using Cake 2 or 3?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to pass the customer ID in the URL for adding an address. You've already used the same concept when the user clicks the link to view a specific customer (and the URL contains the customer ID there).

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Customer id as a parameter for the CustomerAddresses/Add function.

In your Customer View you'll add the link `$this->Html->link(__('New Address'), array('controller' => 'CustomerAddresses', 'action' => add, $this->data['Customer']['id'] ));` given that you loaded `$this->data` with your Customer object on View.

In CustomerAddressesController:

```
public function add( $customer_id = null ) {
    if( !$this->CustomerAddress->Customer->exists($customer_id)
        && empty($this->request->data['CustomerAddress']['customer_id']) ) {
        // Redirect because customer_id does not exist, to avoid SOME security problems
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
    if( $this->request->is('post') ) {
        // Whatever you need for your add function. Customer id will already be in $this->request->data
    }

    $this->set('customer_id', $customer_id);
}
```

And CustomerAddresses/add.ctp in your form add `<input type="hidden" value="<?=$customer_id?>" />`